# understanding lmer random effects in R

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects

What is the point of the "1 +" in (1 + X1|X2) structure of the random effect of an lmer function in lme4 package of R, and how does this differ from (1|X1) + (1|X2)?

Comment: there are several tutorials, but also see https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html

Answer (score 3):

As the comment suggests, looking at the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) might be useful.

`(1+X1|X2)` is identical to `(X1|X2)` (due to R's default of adding an intercept). This fits a model where all of the effects of `X1` (i.e. all of the predictors that we would get from a linear model using `y ~ X1`) vary across the groups/levels defined by `X2`, and all of the correlations among these varying effects are estimated.

- if `X1` is numeric, this fits a random-slopes model that estimates the variation in the intercept across groups, the variation in the slope across groups, and their covariance (correlation).
- if `X1` is categorical (a factor), this estimates variation based on the contrasts used for `X1`. Suppose `X1` has three levels {A, B, C} and the default treatment contrasts are being used. Then a 3x3 covariance matrix is estimated which includes

  - the variation in the intercept (== the expected value in level A) across groups
  - the variation in the *difference* between A and B across groups
  - the variation in the *difference* between A and C across groups
  - all three pairwise covariances/correlations (A vs A-B, A vs A-C, A-B vs A-C)

The formula `(1|X1) + (1|X2)` only makes sense if `X1` is categorical (only categorical variables, or variables that can be treated as categorical, make sense as grouping variables). This estimates the variation in the intercept (baseline response) among levels of `X2` and the variation in the intercept (baseline response) among levels of `X1`.

As a final note, it's hard for me to think of a case where the latter formula (`(1|X1) + (1|X2)`) would make sense as an alternative to `(X1|X2)` ...